# React Flux: what's the point of actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

In `Flux`, what is the point of using `actions`, instead of just letting the `component` publish directly to the `dispatcher`? What is it that I can't do without `actions`?

Comment: There's nothing you couldn't do without actions, however, it's simply a pattern they've established to encourage a particular style of programming. http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html Some might suggest they're more testable, but again, there are other ways of doing that.

Comment: They form the API of the application.  Collecting them in one place makes it easy to reuse them in different parts of the application.

Answer (score 3):

The action creators decouple the component from the dispatcher. You could replace the dispatcher and related pieces with something else and the components would not need to change.